# exe file made by pyinstaller has delay on other computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm using Python 3.5, and I made an exe flle with pyinstaller.

I made exe file successfully, and it runs well on my computer.

But, when I run it on other computer, it has delay.

I made exe file by coding 'pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole THEFILE.py'

What's the problem?

Comment: delay of how much?

Comment: As Nihal already asked, how much of a delay are we speaking of here? And what are the differences in specs between the computers (processor, 32/64-bit OS, HHD or SDD etc.)?

Comment: @Nihal On my computer, the build computer, the program starts wihtin 7 seconds, but on other computer, it starts over 10 to 15 seconds. And also, the program works slowly.

Comment: @Filnor Well, two computers have only one difference, which is that build computer uses SSD, but the other computer uses HDD. Everthing else is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this delay (according to the OP from of 3 to 8 seconds slower) comes from the HDD which is (due to the storage technology that it uses) slower than an SSD. If you can, I would suggest either:

1. Optimize your code to be less disk-incriminating
2. Upgrade from a HDD to an SSD

But keep in mind that both options require some actions, so consider *first* if it's really worth or if you can live with that performance.

Comment: Thank you very much. What does it means to optimize my code to be less disk-incriminating?

Comment: That the code is less disk-intensive, so that the program doesn't get throttled by a slow disk. That could be done by, for example, using a smaller library or such things. But that's hard to tell without knowing the actual code.